# Undefined variable submit at PHPMaker custome template

Tags: php, ssh, dns

```
<?php 
if (!isset($_POST['submit1'])==($submit == "Dig Gmail")){
if (!function_exists("ssh2_connect")) 
die("function ssh2_connect doesn't exist");
$connection = ssh2_connect('x.x.x.x', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'xxxx', 'xxxx');
$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, 'dig @127.0.0.1 gmail.com');
$errorStream = ssh2_fetch_stream($stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDERR);
if (stream_set_blocking($stream, true)) {
echo "<pre>"; 
echo "Output:".stream_get_contents($stream);
echo "</pre>";
} elseif (stream_set_blocking($errorStream, true)) {
echo "Error:".stream_get_contents($errorStream); 
} else {
echo "No Output";
} fclose($errorStream);
  fclose($stream);
}
?>

<form action="" method="post">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" 
name="submit1" value="Dig Gmail">
</form>
```

the message for error code is 
Notice: Undefined variable: submit in C:\xampp\htdocs\coba\home.php on line 402 
thanks for your advice

Comment: Please have a look at [How to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mvce).

Comment: There is literally no CSS in this question, the connection to Linux is obscure at best, MySQL shows up nowhere in the code, and there's no JavaScript code at all. Please tag things properly.

Answer (score 0):

You are using POST variables from your form below, therefore you should use the `$_POST` array, containing the variables submitted from the from.

The above example would work in some older PHP versions with insecure `registre_globals` turned on (which is never a good idea). Also the name was wrong.

Modify the line

```
if (!isset($_POST['submit1'])==($submit == "Dig Gmail")){
```

to

```
if (!isset($_POST['submit1'])==($_POST['submit1'] == "Dig Gmail")){
```

and it should do the job for you.

Comment: Thank Jakuje for your advise ..and iam sory all for mistake in tag